# How to use function mallopt to release memory in the heap under the ndk-tool chains?

Tags: c++, c, linux, android-ndk

I want ro release memory in the heap using ndk-tool chains .
And I konw a function called mallopt , but I don't know how to use it !

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want the `free` function.

Comment: Since the `mallopt()` function is not standardised, though it is fairly common, you need to identify and read the manual page for the implementation you are using.  I don't recall it having an option to release unused memory back to the o/s, which might be what you're looking for, but it is a very long time since I used it (think 25 years and counting).

Comment: Please explain why you think you need this, this really sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)